# How to Change Font-Size Customer Refrence No. in fedx Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want Change the font of fedx customer reference number during fedEx label creation. Please suggest me anyone  is it possible?. I am using .Net core.

This is the my code:

```
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval] = new CustomerReference();
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval].CustomerReferenceType = CustomerReferenceType.CUSTOMER_REFERENCE;
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval].Value = shipDetails1.FirstOrDefault().reference_no;
```

I have tried this:

```
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval] = new CustomerReference();
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval].CustomerReferenceType = CustomerReferenceType.CUSTOMER_REFERENCE;
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval].Value = "<b>" +shipDetails1.FirstOrDefault().reference_no + "</b>";
```

But in output It is showing:

> <B> 123456 <B>

But I want to bold particular value.

Comment: can we get rid of `request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].CustomerReferences[refval]` and just do `var xyz = new CustomerReference();` pain in the ass to read

Comment: Does the thing that is rendering the output accept HTML?